# vertex arithmetic with tikz-feynman

Tags: coordinates, feynman, tikz-feynman

In this MWE (minimal working example)

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (it) at (0, 0);
    \vertex (ib) at ($(it) + (1.1, 1.1)$);
    \diagram*
        {
          (it) -- [photon] (ib),
          (1, 2) -- [fermion] (ib),
        };
       \draw[->] (1, 2) -- (ib);
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

At lines

```
\vertex (ib) at ($(it) + (1.1, 1.1)$);
\draw[->] (1, 2) -- (ib);
```

one can see the flexibility of tikz in defining coordinates. However, the on-the-fly coordinate `(1,2)` at line

```
(1, 2) -- [fermion] (ib),
```

is not accepted.

Nevertheless, it is highly desirable to define coordinates and perform coordinate arithmetic inside the scope of `\diagram`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\diagram` (and `\diagram*`) commands from [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman))  use the `graphdrawing` library from Ti*k*Z which use algorithms in order determine the placement of nodes.  These algorithm cannot handle pure coordinates so unfortunately, it will never be possible to have

```
\diagram* {
  (1, 2) -- (i1),
};
```

Having said that, here are two alternatives which might help you.

## Nailing Vertices

It is possible to give a hint to the algorithm as to the final placement of the vertex with `desired at=<coordinate>`; however, some algorithms do not support this and will disregard the hint entirely.

To be more forceful, it is possible to use the `nail at=<coordinate>` which not only gives the hint to the algorithm, but then disregards the coordinate calculated by the underlying algorithm and overrides it with the specified coordinate.  As this is quite a brute-force method, it may lead to some surprising results.

Here's an example of the keys in action which specify everything completely in order to create a slight slant for the boson line:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \diagram {
      i1 [nail at={(-2, 1)}]
      -- [fermion] a
      -- [fermion] i2 [nail at={(-2, -1)}],
      a [nail at={(-1, 0.2)}] -- [boson] b [nail at={(1, -0.2)}],
      f1 [nail at={(2, 1)}]
      -- [fermion] b
      -- [fermion] f2 [nail at={(2, -1)}],
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that since coordinates have a comma `,`, it is necessary to surround the coordinate in braces `{}` otherwise Ti*k*Z will understand that comma as denoting the start of the next option.

As you can see, this can quickly become quite messy with all the extra coordinate, and I don't think this provides much of an improvement over using the `\vertex` command beforehand.

## Nudging Vertices

If what you are really interested in is providing little tweaks to certain vertices, then these can be specified with the `nudge` family of commands (see §27.6 of the PGF/Ti*k*Z Manual).  This still uses the coordinate automatically calculated by the algorithm, but then nudges the coordinate slightly before drawing everything.

An example of the nudge in action to create a similar diagram as above:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a [nudge up=0.2cm] -- [boson] b [nudge down=0.2cm],
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]