# Draw circles in tikz-feynman

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman

I'm trying to draw this diagram on LuaLaTex using Tikz-Feynman [image: diagram]

But using the code

```
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
a--b,
a  --  b --[quarter left] c--d --[quarter left] b,
c -- [quarter left] e -- [quarter left] d,
e--g,
};
```

I get this strange thing

[image: strange]

Besides the dots on vertices, how can I make the loops more "circular"?

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of a code snippet. This makes our life easier and increases the chance of people helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

- place the `[dot]` option after the point (b, c,...)
- `nudge` c `up` and d `down` a little after these points
- I assumed you want fermions to enter and exit
- compile with LuaLaTex

To understand about nudging w.r.t this package, see here: [vertex arithmetic with tikz-feynman](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377219/vertex-arithmetic-with-tikz-feynman/377291#377291)

[image: diagram with fermions]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
    a-- [fermion, momentum=\(k\)] b [dot],% < fermion, dot
    
    a  --  b --[quarter left] c [dot, nudge up=1cm] % < nudge
        -- d [dot, nudge down=1cm] --[quarter left] b,% < dot, nudge
    c -- [quarter left] e [dot] -- [quarter left] d,% < dot
    
    e-- [fermion, momentum=\(k\)] g,% < fermion
};


\end{document}
```