# TikZ-Feynman line with mixed styles

Tags: diagrams, tikz-feynman, feynman

I'm trying to draw Feynman diagrams like the ones in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.01356.pdf) with `tikz-feynman`:[image]

I don't know how to make these edges that switch from straight to wiggly. I suppose I could break them up as two edges, but that looks ugly:
[image]

This was generated with

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
a -- b -- [boson] c
-- [boson, quarter left] d -- [quarter left] e
-- [half left] c,
e -- [boson] f -- g,
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post an MWE, that would only have to be refined, so to speak?

Comment: I haven't tried much since I simply don't know what to do for the linestyle, but I'll post an example that technically works but is ugly.

Comment: For my understanding, did you check the packages manual?

Comment: Yes, it's here: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1601/1601.05437.pdf
Pages 18-20 have various styles, but none are like the one I need.

Comment: Ok. See p. 29, between a4 and a2 there are the options in and out. These determine entry and exit angles, i.e. like with Beziere curves you can bend your lines as needed. These are standard tikz options.

Comment: Thanks (I think you mean p. 22). I'm still curious if this can be done directly with a (custom?) style since I don't want to multiply edges if it isn't necessary.

Comment: P. 29 in the latest version on ctan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find analysis and two potential solutions. A *third one* may be to contact the author of package `tikz-feynman` and ask for a combined particle, whatever that shall mean.

**Solution 1:** The **misplacement** comes from the auto-placement algorithm used with this package, which is intentionally quite *"ignorant"* to positioning requests. See this link for details: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377291/245790 , and the feynman diagram in the upper right part of the screenshot (adjusted **loop** example from the manual, using an intermediate point bb).

Unfortunately the `nail at` option didn't work for me, while the `nudge down` did. To assist this manual adjustement I put a help grid to estimate the required nudging.

**Solution 2:** You can always draw such diagrams manually with `tikz` (you'll find many examples while searching this site). See some examples below the feynman diagrams, and refer to chp. 24.4 in the pgf-manual. While these pathes are straight lines, you could also use arcs, select arrow tips of your liking, and placing them where they should be.

[image: examples]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.shapes}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\tikz{
    % help grid
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);

    % see placement problems at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377291/245790
    \feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
        a -- [photon, momentum=\(p\)] b
        -- [fermion, quarter left] bb [nudge down=1cm]% as suggested
        -- [photon, quarter left, momentum=\(k\)] c
        -- [fermion, half left, momentum=\(k-p\)] b,
        c -- [photon, momentum=\(p\)] d,
    };

    % ~~~ for reference: adjustedloops example from manual ~~~~
    \feynmandiagram [layered layout, horizontal=b to c] {
        a -- [photon, momentum=\(p\)] b
        -- [fermion, quarter left] bb% <<< intermediate coordinate
        -- [photon, quarter left, momentum=\(k\)] c
        -- [fermion, half left, momentum=\(k-p\)] b,
        c -- [photon, momentum=\(p\)] d,
    };
}

% ~~~ an alternative, doing it all manually ~~~~~~~~~~
% ~~~ allows you to introduce and place arrow tip as needed ~~~
% ~~~ path can also be an arc etc.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw                   (0, 2.5)    --  (3, 2.5);% line
    \draw [ decorate, 
            decoration={coil, aspect=0,
            pre length=2cm}]                    % see chp. 24.4 in pgf-manual
                            (0, 2)  --  (3, 2);% sin. w. pre length
    \draw [ decorate, 
            decoration={coil, aspect=0,
            pre length=1cm}]
                            (0, 1.5)    --  (3, 1.5);% sin. w. pre length
                            
    \draw [ decorate, 
            decoration={coil, aspect=1}]
                            (0, 1)  --  (3, 1);% extended spring
    \draw [ decorate, 
            decoration={coil, aspect=0}]
                            (0, .5) --  (3, .5);% sinosoidal
                            
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been using tikz manually and it's been ok, if a bit verbose. I will accept your answer in a while if noone comes up with a better solution directly in tikz-feynman.